# How to make jquery post request to php script every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you guys show me how i can make jquery post request to a php script every 30 seconds ? The Php script is writing some data to mysql.

```
$.ajax(
{

    type: 'POST',
    url: './postIt.php',

     data: {
     title: 'test',

     },
     success: function (good)
     {
     //handle success

     //alert(good)
     },
     failure: function (bad)
     {
     //handle any errors

     //alert(bad)

     }


});
```

Comment: Did you search _at all_?

Comment: Why not put the ajax call in a function and use a javascript setInterval() function to call the your ajax function every 30 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send Ajax request on every 1s using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310118/how-to-send-ajax-request-on-every-1s-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You could use set interval to continually poll like so.

```
    $(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './postIt.php',

            data: {
                title: 'test',
            },
            success: function(good) {
                //handle success

                //alert(good)
            },
            failure: function(bad) {
                //handle any errors

                //alert(bad)

            }
        });
    }, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) or [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for this